# Formatting of the Title (string) of a YouTube Channel

Tags: string, fonts, youtube, format

How does one create the font/formatting of the '  ' title?
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCscW5crlGp53NIBtD47zlYQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode Characters: *'MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL N' (U+1D40D)* ...
https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d40d/index.htm